# How do I color in Unity using if statements?

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

I am having a problem with coloring.  I think I have some order of operations issue going on, but I really am not sure what is going on.

Here is an overview of the problem.  I have a CrowdManager script that changes the crowd.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CrowdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum crowdOptions
    {None,TeamA,TeamB};

    public crowdOptions CrowdOptions;

    public static CrowdManager instance = null;

    void Awake ()
    {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        } else if (instance != this) {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        ChangeCrowd ();
    }
}
public void ChangeCrowd ()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("crowd")) {
        instance.crowdCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("crowd");
        print (instance.crowdCount);
    } else {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("crowd", instance.crowdCount);
    }
}

    if (instance.crowdCount <= 0) {
        instance.crowdCount += Random.Range (1, 3);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("crowd", instance.crowdCount);

        if (Random.value < .33) {
            instance.CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.None;

        } else if (Random.value > .66) {
            instance.CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.TeamA;

        } else {
            instance.CrowdOptions = crowdOptions.TeamB;

        }
        // Change the crowd in the game!
    } 

    print (instance.CrowdOptions);
}
```

This randomly cycles between the three states, teamA, TeamB and None.  This works fine.  I even `print` which Team that the game has been changed to.  The reason for this is that based on the team it is suppose to color my characters.  I have attached a slimmed down version of the color code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Spine;

public class WinManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static WinManager instance = null;

    public Color teamNoneColor;
    public Color teamAColor;
    public Color teamBColor;

    public Color crowdTeamColor;

    public Color[] teamAColors = new Color[4];
    public Color[] teamBColors = new Color[4];

    void Awake ()
    {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        } else if (instance != this) {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        TeamColorsSelected ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame last
    void LateUpdate ()
    {
        if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.None) {
            //script
        }
        if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.TeamA) {
            //script
        }
        if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.TeamB) {
            //script
        }
    }

    public void TeamColorsSelected ()
    {
        //Team A Colors
        teamAColors [0] = new Color (.10f, .35f, .75f, 1);
        teamAColors [1] = new Color (.37f, .19f, .58f, 1);
        teamAColors [2] = new Color (.32f, .01f, .02f, 1);
        teamAColors [3] = new Color (1f, .58f, .14f, 1);

        //Team B Colors
        teamBColors [0] = new Color (.39f, .60f, .83f, 1);
        teamBColors [1] = new Color (0f, .30f, .15f, 1);
        teamBColors [2] = new Color (1f, .89f, .17f, 1);
        teamBColors [3] = new Color (0f, .14f, .29f, 1);

        teamAColor = teamAColors [Random.Range (0, teamAColors.Length)];
        teamBColor = teamBColors [Random.Range (0, teamBColors.Length)];
        teamNoneColor = new Color (0, 1, 0, 1); //green

        if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.TeamB) {
            crowdTeamColor = teamBColor;
        }
        if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.TeamA) {
            crowdTeamColor = teamAColor;
        }
        if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.None) {
            crowdTeamColor = teamNoneColor;
        }

        //CrowdMember Coloring
        teamCrowdMember = GameObject.Find ("RightCrowdMember").GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        crowdTeamMemberColor = teamCrowdMember.gameObject.GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation> ();

        TeamColorUpdate ();
    }

    public void TeamColorUpdate ()
    {
        //CrowdManager Clothing Colors
        crowdTeamMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("torso").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);
        crowdTeamMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("sleeve_left").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);
        crowdTeamMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("sleeve_right").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);
    }
}
```

The problem is in this area:

```
if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.TeamB) {
    crowdTeamColor = teamBColor;
            }
if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.TeamA) {
    crowdTeamColor = teamAColor;
            }
if (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions == CrowdManager.crowdOptions.None) {
    crowdTeamColor = teamNoneColor;
            }
```

If I set the `crowdTeamColor = teamNoneColor`  or any of the other direct colors.  the crowdTeamColor works, but with the if statement the first time the game loads it sets it to whatever the first teams color was and then doesn't change after that.  Even though the script is running in the `Start()`  I have tried doing if else statements as well I thought maybe separating them individually would force it to work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry for the code vomit, but I felt like I needed to show everything related to this issue.

Here is a link to the "Solution" (work in progress): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145664/how-do-i-color-in-unity-using-is-statements-solution

Comment: I don't see any code that sets `CrowdOptions`.  Also why is `CrowdManager` derived from `MonoBehaviour`?

Comment: I added the crowd options.  They are in two different scripts.

Comment: That doesn't mean it needs to be derived from `MonoBehaviour` and use the singleton pattern.  Looks over-engineered.

Comment: That very well may be the case. I am learning and this way was working as I created it :-)

Comment: All you are getting from the class is the `enum`.  Throw the class away and put the `enum` into `WinManager.`  Use a setter method to set the team enum and make the method also choose the colours automatically for you.  Keep it simple.  Also you definitely want `if else` in that code.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this.   Once I get this working my next goal is to clean the code.

Comment: Tim, **DO NOT** use singletons in unity.  (don't use them generally, unless you are an expert.)  Do what trojan says about taking away the monobehaviour.  **DO NOT** use LateUpdate, there is no need for it and it's making problems.

Comment: Definitely never, ever use "if else".  For any reason - ever.  Until you die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to the post.  Thanks for the help!  Sorry for making things confusing :-)

Note I have cleaned up some of the code to make it easier to read in chunks.

CrowdManager.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CrowdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CrowdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum CrowdTypes
    {
        None,
        TeamA,
        TeamB}
    ;

    public CrowdTypes crowdOptions;

    public int crowdCount = 5;
    public float crowdRandomRole;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        ChangeCrowd ();
    }

    public void ChangeCrowd ()
    {
        if (crowdCount <= 0) {
            crowdCount += Random.Range (1, 3);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("crowd", crowdCount);

            crowdRandomRole = Random.value;

            if (crowdRandomRole < .33) {
                crowdOptions = CrowdTypes.None;
            } else if (crowdRandomRole > .66) {
                crowdOptions = CrowdTypes.TeamA;
            } else {
                crowdOptions = CrowdTypes.TeamB;
            }
    }
}
```

WinManager.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Spine;


public class WinManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CrowdManager cm;

    public bool yayButton = false;
    public bool booButton = false;

    public Color teamNoneColor;
    public Color teamAColor;
    public Color teamBColor;

    public Color crowdTeamColor;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        SetTeamColors ();
        TeamColorsSelected ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        rightCrowdMemberAnimate = GameObject.Find ("RightCrowdMember").GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation> ();
        leftCrowdMemberAnimate = GameObject.Find ("LeftCrowdMember").GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation> ();


        if (cm.crowdOptions == CrowdManager.CrowdTypes.None) {

            //script
        }
        if (cm.crowdOptions == CrowdManager.CrowdTypes.TeamA) {

            //script
        }
        if (cm.crowdOptions == CrowdManager.CrowdTypes.TeamB) {

            //script
        }
    }

    public void SetTeamColors ()
    {
        //Team A Colors
        teamAColors [0] = new Color (.10f, .35f, .75f, 1f);
        teamAColors [1] = new Color (.37f, .19f, .58f, 1f);
        teamAColors [2] = new Color (.32f, .01f, .02f, 1f);
        teamAColors [3] = new Color (1f, .58f, .14f, 1f);

        //Team B Colors
        teamBColors [0] = new Color (.39f, .60f, .83f, 1f);
        teamBColors [1] = new Color (0f, .30f, .15f, 1f);
        teamBColors [2] = new Color (1f, .89f, .17f, 1f);
        teamBColors [3] = new Color (0f, .14f, .29f, 1f);

        teamAColor = teamAColors [Random.Range (0, 3)];
        teamBColor = teamBColors [Random.Range (0, 3)];
        teamNoneColor = new Color (0f, 1f, 0f, 1f); //green

    }

    public void TeamColorsSelected ()
    {

        //ScoreBoard Team Colors
        Image scoreBoardRed = GameObject.Find ("ScoreBoardRed").GetComponent<Image> ();
        scoreBoardRed.color = teamAColor;
        Image scoreBoardBlue = GameObject.Find ("ScoreBoardBlue").GetComponent<Image> ();
        scoreBoardBlue.color = teamBColor;

        //  crowdTeamColor = teamAColor;

        if (cm.crowdOptions == CrowdManager.CrowdTypes.TeamB) {
            crowdTeamColor = teamBColor;
        }
        if (cm.crowdOptions == CrowdManager.CrowdTypes.TeamA) {
            crowdTeamColor = teamAColor;
        }
        if (cm.crowdOptions == CrowdManager.CrowdTypes.None) {
            crowdTeamColor = teamNoneColor;
        } 

        //CrowdMember Coloring
        rightCrowdMemberRender = GameObject.Find ("RightCrowdMember").GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        rightCrowdMemberColor = rightCrowdMemberRender.gameObject.GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation> ();

        leftCrowdMemberRender = GameObject.Find ("LeftCrowdMember").GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        leftCrowdMemberColor = leftCrowdMemberRender.gameObject.GetComponent<SkeletonAnimation> ();

        TeamColorUpdate ();
    }

    public void TeamColorUpdate ()
    {
        //rightTeamMember Color Jersey
        rightCrowdMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("torso").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);
        rightCrowdMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("sleeve_left").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);
        rightCrowdMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("sleeve_right").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);

        //rightTeamMember Color Jersey
        leftCrowdMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("torso").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);
        leftCrowdMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("sleeve_left").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);
        leftCrowdMemberColor.skeleton.FindSlot ("sleeve_right").SetColor (crowdTeamColor);

    }
}
```

I figured it out.  I needed to Update the

```
TeamColorsSelected ()
```

And it all worked!  Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the problem right then try using switch case statement with default branch.
Something like this might work.

```
switch (CrowdManager.instance.CrowdOptions) {
    case CrowdManager.crowdOptions.TeamB : 
        crowdTeamColor = teamBColor;
        break;
    case CrowdManager.crowdOptions.TeamA : 
        crowdTeamColor = teamAColor;
        break;
    case CrowdManager.crowdOptions.None :
    default : 
        crowdTeamColor = teamNoneColor;
        break;
}
```

Also CrowdManager.crowdOptions should be enum. If it is not a basic type then try using Equals method instead of == statement.

Comment: While this is the much better approach, it will give the same result so won't solve the issue.